# How to insert data in the form of dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Everyone I have the data in the source system as '**dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm**' so i thought of using datetime in snowflake, but the documentation says that the format is '**dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss**' so it throws me an error stating that

> Timestamp '01/02/2009 04:53' is not recognized

so in this scenario what should i do in order to store the data in snowflake if the source system is in this format.

**Possible solutions that i have found out is:**
**

- 1: Store the data of the column in the format of 'varchar(x)' of fixed length, which
  might be a good solution but, is there any other alternative to store
  the data as datetime without converting it into 'varchar(x)'.
- 2: varchar(x) is the datatype of the timestamp with length 'x' which is **'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss'**.

**The Schema Looks like this:**

- 1: Sample schema of the table is
  **CREATE TABLE T1(ID INTEGER,TRANSACTION_DATE DATETIME)**
- 2: Here is the link for reference, to the datatype manual in snowflake.
  (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#datetime)
- 3: Newbie Here, Please pardon me,if there are any typo's ! thanks in advance.
  **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change your timestamp input format for your session when loading data:

```
create or replace table test_table (v datetime);

alter session set TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI';

insert into test_table values ('01/02/2009 04:53'); -- works
```

TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-timestamp-input-format

Or you can use transformation with your copy command:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#convert-data-types-during-a-load